# Why am I getting the error AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I know this question has been asked before but nothing I have read so far seems to fix the problem.  My ASP.NET Core application receives the following error message when I try to run it.

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the
>   reply URLs configured for the application

I have set up my authentication using the guide given to me by the Azure Portal.  I'll show you what I have so far.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("NorwayTeam", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "111-222-333-444-555"));
    });            

    //MVC
    services.AddMvc(options => {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

    ...[shortened for brevity]
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        routes.MapHub<VesselHub>("/vesselHub");
        routes.MapHub<RequirementHub>("/requirementHub");
    });
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I've also placed the relative code in my `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "MyCompany.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

So, from the perspective of the application, the above code is all that's needed to connect to my app registration.  Obviously, I have placed `[Authorize]` in the relative controllers.

The next step is to set up the app registration in my Azure portal.  I changed my app registration settings to the following, the blurred out areas use the URL of my web app which is `https://MyCompany.azurewebsites.net/`.  Since this is my production version of my application I don't want to use `localhost`.

[image: App Registration Settings]

Part of me thinks that the problem could be related to a rogue localhost declaration but I can't be sure as I can't see what request is being made by the application to the app registration.  Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: Did you also update **Home page URL** on **Branding** tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem.  What I didn't realise during the setup of all of this is that a single app registration in Azure can have many return URLs for both `localhost` and for your `production` environment.

To make this application work and overcome the error, I simply added an additional URL set to the app registration for both `production` and `staging` thus giving me the capability to authenticate on all avenues.  Please see below.

[image: App Registration Return URLs]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was typing in the browser:

```
mysite.azurewebsites.net
```

but Chrome was completing the url with `http`. When I manually typed:

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net
```

The problem was gone.

Comment: Turns out that was my case too. And that's surprising. I've got this bug on 2 mobile browsers - Chrome itself and Edge (new one, based on Chromium). With all force move to https it still opens http by default. So I had to turn on "HTTPS only" setting in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to locate this issue, when you access your application url(`https://MyCompany.azurewebsites.net/`), you will be redirect to the login page.

[image]

Decode the authorize request url, you will find the redirect_uri.

It is something like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:59775/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid profile
```

Copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it to azure portal, then try again.

Comment: My case the redirect_uri is http://localhost:59775/test1/. I have 100 of tests component from test1 to test100.The problem is that I can't add 100 redirect_uri like this to the azure portal. Is there anyway to solve it?